# SQL Server Integration Services: how to manage multiple sources?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, union

I merged two databases for analyses purposes. One of these databases is out of production, so the data is not changing. The other db is live and continuously growing.

What's the best practice in terms of data management/storage? Do I have to delete all rows and reload + union data from both databases or is there a better way to manage this?

Thanks in advance
Sam

Comment: I flagged this as opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the SSIS then make a package which will check keys and based on that it will inserted only unique rows.

You can easily apply lookup via ssis in source and destination.

Let me know if you need any help